# PHP strtotime() function off using "1-January-2013"

Tags: php, mysql, string, time

I am collecting a user's birthday from a registration form and am hoping to convert this to a timestamp using strtotime before storing it in a database, but this isn't going so well.

I have them select their date in 3 select boxes, one is for the day, another the month, and lastly the year, and then I feed those into strtotime. The problem is, I am inputting "1", "January", and "2013" for the variables previously listed and am feeding them into strtotime like this:

```
$user->birthday = strtotime($input['bday'].'-'.$input['bmonth'].'-'.$input['byear']);
```

This reads when echoed as "1-January-2013", yet the timestamp it spits out renders to "Dec 31, 2012" using:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
echo date("M d, Y", 1356998400);
```

I have been testing different methods profusely but cannot get this to work. I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Did you call `date_default_timezone_set` before calling `strtotime`?

Comment: I believe my framework sets that. It's set to UTC.

Comment: So you're processing the input date in UTC, then echoing it in LA time. When it's Jan 1 in Greenwhich, it's still Dec 31 in LA.

Comment: Oh shoot...*facepalm*...Gosh..thanks. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `date_default_timezone_set` before calling `strtotime`, so that you have the same timezones when parsing the input date and when you're displaying the date.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting date_default_timezone_set() before the call to strtotime() or after? Since the default timezone is UTC, and LA is UTC-08.00, that could account for the difference.

Comment: Questions should be asked in comments. I know, you don't have enough rep to comment yet. But I already asked this question, so you don't need to.

Comment: Yes, this was precisely it, thanks. Barmar solved it first, unfortunately, or I would accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how your code is failing, but this works for me:

```
// Set the test data.
$test_data = '1-January-2013';

// Get the Unix datetime from the test data.
$date = strtotime($test_data);

// Format the Unix datetime.
$dateFormat = date("M d, Y", $date);  

// Output for debugging.
echo 'test_data: ' . $date . '<br />';
echo 'date: ' . $date . '<br />';
echo 'dateFormat: ' . $dateFormat . '<br />';
```

Output from my side using PHP 5.5 is:

```
test_data: 1357016400
date: 1357016400
dateFormat: Jan 01, 2013
```

But on the outside chance those `-` dashes are choking things, try this:

```
// Set the test data.
$test_data = '1-January-2013';

// Filter out dashes from the '$test_data'
$test_data = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $test_data);

// Get the Unix datetime from the test data.
$date = strtotime($test_data);

// Format the Unix datetime.
$dateFormat = date("M d, Y", $date);  

// Output for debugging.
echo 'test_data: ' . $date . '<br />';
echo 'date: ' . $date . '<br />';
echo 'dateFormat: ' . $dateFormat . '<br />';
```

And again, the output from my side using PHP 5.5 is:

```
test_data: 1357016400
date: 1357016400
dateFormat: Jan 01, 2013
```

Comment: Did you get this timestamp? Maybe it's my env... "1356998400"

Comment: For me `echo date(strtotime("1".'-'."January".'-'."2013"));` gives `1356994800`.

Comment: But when I just checked all the timestamps, they all result in Jan 01, 2013.

Comment: Alright guys, sorry, as Barmar said up top, it's because I was inputting in UTC and outputting in PST-8. My bad. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a time zone issue.  1356998400 is 01 / 01 / 13 @ 12:00:00am UTC, so when you do this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
echo date("M d, Y", 1356998400);
```

The Unix time 1356998400 *is* Dec 31, 2012 in Los Angeles!  I suspect you're getting your timestamp in UTC and then outputting it with PST.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened. Thanks again. Unfortunately Barmar got it first, so I'll be accepted his answer.